# Is the units of tkinter root height different from tkinter widget height?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

When I get the height of the root and use the half of the height of root as the height of the widget, it becomes so big. Do they have different units? How do I can I set height of widget to be half the height of root. I need to use this because I need to change the size dynamically.
Thank You

```
     height = top.winfo_height()
     x = int( height/2)
     A11 = tkinter.Text(top, height=x, width=x,background = "#02e0a1")
```

Comment: What does `print(x)` return? Or better yet could you provide what is assigned to `top`?

Answer (score 2):

The height for a Text widget is in number of characters, not pixels.

There are ways to solve this with `pack`, `place`, and `grid`, or you can query tkinter for the height of a line and do a little math. The correct solution really depends on what else is in the window and how you want them to interact when the window is resized.

The most common way to create tkinter apps, and the way that will likely give you the most responsive layout, is to configure your inner widgets to be what they ought to be and let the window grow or shrink to fit.

Comment: If that's the case; one workaround would be to put the Text widget in a Frame parent and configure the Frame's size instead, and then make the Text widget expand inside that frame.